# How to search variable product by its variation id in woocommerce admin product search box?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, search, woocommerce

I am facing the issue that I want to search for every product IDs including product variants in woocommerce admin. How to search product by variation id in woocommerce admin ?

can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is variable products that have "variations". "Variants" doesn't mean anything… **Is not possible to search product "variations"**, as they are variations of the same variable product.

Comment: I need to search products somehow with ID in admin product search box and if it is a variations Id, then parent product will be listed. So that it can be identified, of which product it belongs too.

Comment: I think that this will not work… The only displayed products are all products types except variations (that are not a product type). So the search doesn't work on variations... But may be I am wrong. Your question is too vague and should need to be edited with something clear and detailed, if you want to have any chance for an answer. ("variants" means nothing in woocommerce, instead use"variations")…

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have implement the above functionality by modifying the filter "posts_search".

By using bellow code you can search variable products by their variations id in woocommerce admin product search area.

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'product_search' );

function product_search( $where ) {

    global $pagenow, $wpdb, $wp;

    if ( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || ! is_search() || ! isset( $wp->query_vars['s'] ) || 'product' != $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) {
        return $where;
    }

    $search_ids = array();
    $terms      = explode( ',', $wp->query_vars['s'] );

    foreach ($terms as $term){
        if (is_numeric($term)){
            $post_type = get_post_type( $term );
            if($post_type == 'product_variation'){
                $search_ids[]   =   wp_get_post_parent_id($term);
            }else{
               $search_ids[]   =   $term;
            }
        }
        // Attempt to get a SKU
        $sku_to_id = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_parent FROM {$wpdb->posts} LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE %s;", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( wc_clean( $term ) ) . '%' ) );
        $sku_to_id = array_merge( wp_list_pluck( $sku_to_id, 'ID' ), wp_list_pluck( $sku_to_id, 'post_parent' ) );

        if (sizeof($sku_to_id) > 0) {
            $search_ids = array_merge($search_ids, $sku_to_id);
        }
     }

     $search_ids = array_filter( array_unique( array_map( 'absint', $search_ids ) ) );

    if ( sizeof( $search_ids ) > 0 ) {
        $where = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ( ({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $search_ids ) . ")) OR ((", $where );
    }
    return $where;
}
```